# When I insert value then only last value stored

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");

// Collect services.
$serviceid = "select * from service";
$servicevalue = $conn->query($serviceid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$services = [];
while ($row = $servicevalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $services[] = $row;
}

// Collect activities.
$activityid = "select * from activity";
$activityvalue = $conn->query($activityid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$activities = [];
while ($row = $activityvalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $activities[] = $row;
}

// Collect something else?
$perid = "select * from periodicity";
$pervalue = $conn->query($perid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$pers = [];
while ($row = $pervalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pers[] = $row;
}

foreach ($services as $service):

?>

    <form method="post" action="doalert.php" name="test">  
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name='arr[1][service]' type='checkbox' data-id='Incometax'value="<?php echo $service['service_id']?>"/><?php echo $service['servicename']?>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <?php foreach ($activities as $activity) : ?>

                            <input type='checkbox' name='arr[1][activity][]' value="<?php echo $activity['activity_id']?>" /><?php echo $activity['nameofactivity'];?>
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <?php endforeach;?>

                </ol>

            </li>
        </ul>           
        <br>
<?php endforeach;?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

The value of services and activity come from the database, I want to store all the services and related activity in DB `serviceactivitymap` table, here is my php code but when I store the data then last checked service value only stored with all the activity checked

- incometax

  - filling
  - return
- gst

  - filling
  - return

If incometax,gst,filling,return is checkboxes then when we check :

> incometax->filling,return and gst->filling,return

Then the code only store

> gst->filling,return and gst->filling,return

Instead of :

> incometax->filling,return and gst->filling,return

Comment: You should look at your generated HTML. You start a bunch of tags inside loops but doesn't close them until after. This code should give you a bunch of unclosed tags.

Comment: Where do you insert values in that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `service_id` to the activity name like :

```
<input type='checkbox' name='activity[<?php echo $service['service_id']?>][]' value="<?php echo $activity['activity_id']?>" /><?php echo $activity['nameofactivity'];?>
```

Full form will be like :

```
<form method="post" action="doalert.php" name="test"> 
    <?php foreach ($services as $service): ?>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name='service[]' type='checkbox' data-id='Incometax' value="<?php echo $service['service_id']?>"/><?php echo $service['servicename']?>
                <ol>
                    <?php foreach ($activities as $activity): ?>
                        <li>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='activity[<?php echo $service['service_id']?>][]' value="<?php echo $activity['activity_id']?>" /><?php echo $activity['nameofactivity'];?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank u So much sir , all the problems which i have solved by your answers,Thank u for all the help

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the form start tag is created every time a loop runs as it is inside the service foreach. Try taking it outside the loop

Also, the name you used for service input tag as `arr[1]["service"]` will be overwritten everytime the loop runs. Instead I would suggest if you can use a variable increment in each loop like

```
$i=0;
foreach($services as $service)
{
    .....

    <input name='arr[$i][service]' ...... 

    $i++;
 }
```

This will differentiate the input tag name and saving may happen properly.

Comment: Not to mention that there is one `<li>` before the loop, and a `</li>` inside the loop. And some rouge `<br>` between the `li`'s.

Comment: Agreed with @Magnus Eriksson. Please correct your HTML first.

Comment: I will keep in mind next time ,Thanks for the helpful suggestions and help.

Comment: Glad it helped.